# $resource doesn't get array from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-resource

I would like to get array object from server (java). Below there is angular method :

```
service.getAthors = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var authors = authorResource.query(function() {
            console.log(authors);
        }).$promise.then( function(){
                deferred.resolve( "Adding book have gone correctly." );
            }, function(){
                deferred.reject("Error during adding new book.");
            });
    }
```

In console firebug's i see this: `[{"author_id":7,"author":"Dan Brown"}]` but authors array is empty. Can you tell me why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `authors` to the returned server data.

```
authorResource.query(function() {
        console.log(authors);
    }).$promise.then( function(data){
            authors = data;
            deferred.resolve( "Adding book have gone correctly." );
        }, function(){
            deferred.reject("Error during adding new book.");
        });
```

Comment: Ok. It is working now. But can you tell my why in angular's documentation in Card example is  "var cards = CreditCard.query(function() {" ?

Comment: I need to take a look at your `authorResource` code.

Comment: Try to remove the chaining of  `.$promise.then(...`. Let the code be just `authors = authorResource.query(function() {
        console.log(authors);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };

authorResource.query({isArray:true},function() {
        console.log(authors);
    }).$promise.then( function(data){
            authors = data;
            deferred.resolve( "Adding book have gone correctly." );
        }, function(){
            deferred.reject("Error during adding new book.");
        });
```

you are using query method use  isArray:true

see the reference https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 0):

Angular $resource has a little inconsistence when an action with isArray:true exist.

If you call the resource class and not the instance, works of different ways, example:

```
myModule.controller('controller',function(MyResource){
  //In this MyResource is the class
  var myElement = MyResource.get({id:1});  //myElement is an instance

  var array = MyResource.query(); //When the query response the array gonna be filled

  var arrayFromMyElement = myElement.query() // Return a promise not a array and the data of the promise gonna get the array

  arrayFromMyElement.then(function(data){
    //Data is the array
  })
});
```

This is observable in the $resource source code:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L627-L638